# Issue when running react-native run-android

Tags: java, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I have been working on a React Native Project and formatting it for Android Devices and I am experiencing an error when I run react-native run-android when my virtual device is running in android studio.

```
(node:6887) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
```

this part looks like the usual output

```
> Configure project :app 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.fulcrum:string/app_name) not found.
  /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.fulcrum:style/AppTheme) not found.
```

i think this is where my problem lies but I am not sure where to go from here besides restarting my machine

```
  error: failed processing manifest.

  Command: /Users/timothylowe/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/8a2fe804c00a7bb6586b8d1051c974fb/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/timothylowe/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @/Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
          --custom-package\
          com.fulcrum\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
  Output:  /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.fulcrum:string/app_name) not found.

  /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.fulcrum:style/AppTheme) not found.

  /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.fulcrum:string/app_name) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.
  Command: /Users/timothylowe/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/8a2fe804c00a7bb6586b8d1051c974fb/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/timothylowe/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @/Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
          --custom-package\
          com.fulcrum\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          /Users/timothylowe/myApps/fulcrum/Fulcrum/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
19 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 18 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

not sure what I need to do to get it running.
everything works when I run react-native run-ios

My Build.gradle(Project) flie looks like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
   }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
   distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

```
My build.gradle(Module:app)looks like this:

    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    import com.android.build.OutputFile

    /**
     * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g.     bundleDebugJsAndAssets
     * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
     * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
     * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
     * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
     * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
     * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
     *
     * project.ext.react = [
     *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
     *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
     *
     *   // the entry file for bundle generation
     *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
     *   bundleInDebug: false,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
     *   bundleInRelease: true,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
     *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
     *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
     *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
     *   // bundleInBeta: true,
     *
     *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
     *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
     *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
     *
     *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
     *   root: "../../",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
     *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
     *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
     *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
     *   resourcesDirRelease:                     "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
         *
       *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
       *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
       *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
       *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively,       if you have JS files in android/
       *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
       *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
       *
       *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
       *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
       *
       *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
       *   extraPackagerArgs: []
       * ]
       */

      project.ext.react = [
          entryFile: "index.js"
      ]

      apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

      /**
       * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
       *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
       *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
       * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
       * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
       * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
       */
      def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

      /**
       * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
       */
      def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

      android {
          compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
          buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

          defaultConfig {
              applicationId "com.fulcrum"
              minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
              targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
              versionCode 1
              versionName "1.0"
              ndk {
                  abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
              }
          }
          splits {
              abi {
                  reset()
                  enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                  universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                  include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
              }
          }
          buildTypes {
              release {
                  minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-      android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
              }
          }
          // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
          applicationVariants.all { variant ->
              variant.outputs.each { output ->
                  // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                  // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                  def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
                  def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                  if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                      output.versionCodeOverride =
                              versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      dependencies {
          compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
          implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
          implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-            v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
          implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From       node_modules
      }

      // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
      // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
      task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
          from configurations.compile
          into 'libs'
      }
```

Comment: can you share app/build.gradle file. because it seems problem is in your dependencies.

Comment: i edited my last post to include the build.gradle

Comment: try replace "implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}" " with "implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"". and after this clean and run. Now I know it's the same supportLibVersion but it worked for me. Hope it works..

Comment: and if above doesn't work then try this classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'. Hope one of it works.

Comment: how would I change the classpath? what would i be replacing? 
and your previous advice did not seem to show any changes in the output code

Comment: I m saying if classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' version is not working then try downgrading it to 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `build.gradle` file: Make sure that the version of the Android SDK and any other dependencies in your `build.gradle` file are compatible with your app's resources.

Clean and rebuild the project: In Android Studio, select

> "Build" > "Clean Project" and then "Build" > "Rebuild Project"

This will clean up any temporary files and rebuild your project from scratch.

or try removing node modules -

> rm -rf node_modules

then `npm install`
and `react-native start --reset-cache`